# how can i simplify this function to find the zeros?

Tags: calculus

$(r^2-1)x-r^2(r+1)x^2+2r^3x^3-r^3x^4=0$

All of the variables just have a one digit exponent.. So the biggest exponent is $X^4$

Comment: Hint: Start out by factoring out an $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: there are two linear factors (one of which is obvious) and a quadratic factor.

Answer (score 0):

As Amzoti said, start factoring and this gives you the first obvious solution which is x=0. There is another "simple" root which is (1-1/r). These are the two linear factors mentioned by Robert Israel. Then, performing polynomial division, only a quadratic term will remain. Are you able to continue with this ?

Comment: i understand that x=0 is a solution, but I'm  not following what you mean, are you saying (1-1/r) is a solution? and how can a quadratic remain?

Comment: Replace x by (1-1/r) in your equation; what is the result ? If it is zero, then x = (1-1/r) is a solution. Since your started with a quartic equation and you already have two factors, namaly x and (x - 1 + 1/r), factorization will let you with a quadratic equation.